# PHP Late Static Binding -- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, static, late-binding

Testing some late static binding and getting this error on line 5:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE`

line 5:

`protected static test = 'A TEST';`

Here is the source:

```
class A {

    protected static test = 'A TEST';

    public static function test() {
        echo $this->test;
    }
}

Class B extends A {
    public static test = "B TEST";
    public function static_test() {
        echo static::$test;
    }
}

$a = new A;
$b = new B;

echo '$a->test()<br />';
echo $a->test();
echo '<br /> <br />';
echo '$b->test()<br />';
echo $b->test();
echo '<br /> <br />';
echo '$b->static_test()<br />';
echo $b->static_test();
```

Safe to say I am stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
protected static $test = 'A TEST';
                 ^--- !!!
```

It's not a constant - so it should be preceded by `$` sign

Comment: Heh, always overlooking the simple things.

Comment: @Ryan_K consider clicking on the green tick next to the answer to accept it if it helped.

Comment: Yeah, had to wait before choosing an answer.  (Which is a nice implementation)